# How to Protect program from using on the SERVER?

Tags: asp.net, licensing

I have a progam this is a converter for .NET that can be used in other .NET projects.
I have two kinds of license:

1. Developer license for DESKTOP software
2. Developer license for WEB server deployed software.

How I can protect my program if client buy (1) license he CAN NOT use it on the SERVER.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I don't know anything about .Net, other than how to spell it, and I'm not completely sure about that.

It seems like one difference between a person using your file converter on their desktop and using it on a web server is that only a single instance will be running at a time on the desktop; a web page will probably have multiple instances, once per concurrent request. This seems like something you could enforce in software, and also something you could easily write into a license agreement.

Does IIS run with a graphical console on Windows? If it doesn't, and your desktop version does, maybe you could detect that?

Ultimately, though, if someone wants to get around your server/desktop distinction enough, they're going to; they could, for example, have the web server send the document to a desktop machine, and have the desktop send it back to the server. So, at some point, you'll have to give in and either ignore it or to say *that's a problem for legal to handle.*

Answer (score 1):

If it is desktop software (I'm not sure by the question with the tag), you could use the `Environment` object to check what OS the code is running on and stop it running on Server Technology. This won't help if they run a server using XP or the like though, but it's a start.

Comment: And will piss off anyone who is running a server edition on their desktop, no?

Comment: Yep, however for the software, it makes sense. Disclaimers are fun? :P

Comment: Yes I don't know what OS the client use. It can be XP. Also I can't decrease the functionality of my .NET component, it has only one function for file converting.